# how to disable third party repositories ubuntu 12.04

Tags: add-apt-repository

I wanted to install skype but as I installed the software, it was not correctly installed and gave an error on update that I have to disable third party repository. I want to know what's that mean, how to disable it and doe this effect the system?

Answer (score 10):

You can disable third party repository by following any of two ways:

1. Execute this command in terminal

   ```
   sudo software-properties-gtk
   ```

   In **Software Sources** window go to <kbd>Other Softwares</kbd> .tab and delete or uncheck the repositories listed there. First delete/uncheck the repositories except first four. If it doesn't solve your issue then `Uncheck` the first four also. <kbd>Close</kbd> and run `sudo apt-get update`
2. You can also disable by following these steps:

   **Ubuntu Software Center** > **Edit** > **Software Sources** > <kbd>Other Software</kbd> tab > **clear/uncheck** the check-boxes. Follow the same rule as given in 1st method.

3rd part repository provides additional packages/software which are generally not available in default Ubuntu repository. So disabling it would not cause any issue.

Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: on KDE its `software-properties-kde`