# Unable to create `file' (while processing ): Read-only file syste

Tags: dpkg

I am trying to update my softwares but I get the following error:

```
The package system is broken
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-generic-lts-quantal: Depends: linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic but it is not installed***
```

After this, I tried installing the package `linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic` from the software center but I have the same dialog box as above stating that I have unmet dependencies and I need to install the very same package to install itself.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f

[sudo] password for shashank: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
Suggested packages:
  linux-lts-quantal-doc-3.5.0 linux-lts-quantal-source-3.5.0
  linux-lts-quantal-tools linux-headers-3.5.0-47-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/40.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 158 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 224750 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic (from .../linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic_3.5.0-47.71~precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic_3.5.0-47.71~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/boot/abi-3.5.0-47-generic.dpkg-new' (while processing `./boot/abi-3.5.0-47-generic'): Read-only file system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-runlilo 3.5.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-47-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic_3.5.0-47.71~precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And the output of `uname -r` shows,

```
$ uname -r
3.5.0-44-generic
```

I typed the command `sudo mount` in terminal and following is the output

```
shashank@shashank-HP-ProBook-445-G1:~$ sudo mount
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type vfat (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/shashank/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=shashank)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` like the error suggests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Pos the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` and `uname -r` in your question.

Comment: Like the error report says, first [disable third party repositories](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367083/how-to-disable-third-party-repositories-ubuntu-12-04) and then try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: yes i disabled the updates from third party repositories and then ran these commands

Comment: Close voters, It's not a dupe of that question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remount the file system as read write, otherwise it will fail:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic_3.5.0-47.71~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/boot/abi-3.5.0-47-generic.dpkg-new' (while processing `./boot/abi-3.5.0-47-generic'): Read-only file system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Use `sudo mount | grep -v rw` to find out the device that is mounted as read only, then run:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1
```

Replace `sda1` with whatever is the device that is mounted as readonly, but I'm pretty sure it will be `/boot`.

Comment: i could'nt understand which device is the one we need to rewrite

Comment: @shanky you don't need to *rewrite* but *remount*. Can you update the question with the output of `sudo mount`?

Comment: @shanky it appears the same message?

Comment: yeah sorry, i meant which device to remount.....
i've already put up the output of
'sudo mount'

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue today. And solved it as follows:

In a terminal window...
deleted the downloaded kernel's .deb file, in my case:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic_3.5.0-47.71~precise1_i386.deb
```

then ran the update manager again, refreshing it. Not sure if this did anything but I did it.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This downloaded the deb file anew and installed it just fine.

Hope this helps. It seems, at least in my case, that the deb file had been corrupted during an initial download by the update manager.

Comment: i tried it but this is what i got

**shashank@shashank-HP-ProBook-445-G1:~$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic_3.5.0-45.71~precise1_i386.deb
rm: cannot remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic_3.5.0-45.71~precise1_i386.deb': No such file or directory**