# Ubuntu Software Updater and libpcap0.8 package Issues

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, libpcap

Ubuntu has notified me I have some updates but when trying to update I get this message...

> The package system is broken: Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, sine they area common source of problems. Furthermore run the following commend in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

I have followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367083/how-to-disable-third-party-repositories-ubuntu-12-04) to disable third party repositories and I still have the same issue.

In Terminal as suggested `apt-get install -f` returns this...

```
telos182@imaLaptop:/$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpcap0.8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpcap0.8
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/117 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 220047 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcap0.8:amd64 (1.7.4-2) over (1.4.0-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz', which is different from other instances of package libpcap0.8:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Furthermore `apt-get remove` gives me this...

```
telos182@imaLaptop:/$ sudo apt-get remove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8 : Breaks: libpcap0.8:i386 (!= 1.4.0-2) but 1.7.4-2 is installed
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Breaks: libpcap0.8 (!= 1.7.4-2) but 1.4.0-2 is installed
 libpcap0.8-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8 (= 1.7.4-2) but 1.4.0-2 is installed
 tcpdump : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And `apt-get remove -f` as it suggests comes back with this...

```
telos182@imaLaptop:/$ sudo apt-get remove -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
 libpcap0.8
The following packages will be upgraded:
 libpcap0.8
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/117 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 220047 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcap0.8:amd64 (1.7.4-2) over (1.4.0-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz', which is different from other instances of package libpcap0.8:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.7.4-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have a very good idea of how this all happened but sadly have not been able to address the issue :(

Comment: Dpkg is failing when it tries to overwrite a file in the manual pages.  You could rename the file that is being overwritten `sudo mv /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz.old` and then execute `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: This seems to have worked quite well, thank you very much. I had to repeat your suggestion a few times on some other files before all was well, dealing with them one by one, about 5 in all I think.